# Why does Windows Error Reporting create two mini-dump files for each crash with Visual Studio installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, windows-error-reporting

I followed [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to set up mini-dump collection on the Windows 10 machine. I set up the following keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpFolder"="C:\CrashDumps"
"DumpCount"=dword:00000100
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
```

The `"C:\CrashDumps"` folder's `ACL` is set up for the `full access` for `Everyone`.

Now when I'm testing it with a deliberately crashing app running the following C++ code:

```
BYTE* p = (BYTE*)rand();
*p = 1;
```

The app crashes but then I get two `.dmp` files in the folder:

[image]

This seems to be happening only with Visual Studio installed.

Why is it doing it? And is there a setting to make it create only one mini-dump file?

Comment: Presumably because VS already creates the dump when you're running from the IDE. As far as *is there a setting to make it create only one*, yes. Remove the one you manually added to the registry.

Comment: @KenWhite: No, I'm starting this `TestApp.exe` from Windows Explorer. IDE is not even running. It's just installed.